# how to make a pass word that will redirect me to another page only when its correct. all while staying on the same tab

Tags: html, passwords, redirect

I'm a beginner and I'm using HTML to embed aspects onto google sites. forgive me if my title wasn't specific or my question is idiotic.
this is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">

<form class="form1" action= "sites.google.com" onsubmit="return (this.pass.value==='1291')?true:false;">

    <div class="formtitle">Enter the password to proceed</div>

    <div class="input nobottomborder">
        <div class="inputtext">Password: </div>
        <div class="inputcontent">

           <input type="password" name="pass" />
            <br/>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">

        <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Login" />


    </div>
```

the problem is it will redirect me to the other page on a new tab that it opens is there any way to keep it on the same tab?

another problem is that it will show the password in the URL is there any way to prevent that?

thanks for your help